# PlayFramework Java Project Compilation Failure- "scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found"

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm new to the Play Framework, but can't get anything done because I've been getting the above  compile time error.

> scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found

The project I'm compiling is a java-based simple 'Hello, World' type app. I've never used Scala, but have recently installed it from the official website to see if it would remedy the situation (which it has not).

If it makes any difference, I'm running 2.2.1

Now, I've seen similar questions, but always for Scala projects and not Java projects.

Is it that I need the web pages to compile to Java instead? And if so how do I do that?
If not, any solutions?

Comment: You do not need to install a additional Java or Scala Compiler, these are bundled in the playframework directory. Have you downloaded and extracted the playframework somewhere to your disc? Have you put the play executeable folder to your PATH? What is appearing, when you type `play` on the commandline? When you say "compiling" do you mean compiling in your IDE (because that is not needed, play does this for you)? Have you read the quickstart tutorial on http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList to get basic understanding how play works?

Comment: The Play Framework is installed and in my PATH.
By compiling, I'm referring to the results I get when I type `play ~run` into the command line, from the folder in which my project is saved.
I'm not using an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exception for the hello-akka template using typesafe activator a few days ago.

I think it had something to do with the activator*shim.sbt files in the root and project directories.

If I comment out their contents, I can run sbt manually and run the project with the run command inside the sbt prompt.

Inside those files were lines like

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse", % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.3.0")`

I didn't solve the problem, but I didnt need the plugins at the time.  I commented out those lines and SBT was able to run without the exception.

I'm using activator-1.1.2 the version in the hello-akka build.sbt is 1.0

When manually running sbt in the template directory, I used the tar of sbt from http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html version 13.2.

Comment: Strange, I ran into this problem with the 'classic' installation, and resorted to Activator when it didn't work.

I'm not entirely sure why, but on my newer laptop, the Play Framework works without a hitch.

Comment: Yeah its a strange error.  I ran into it again with the 2.3 versions of play(now activator) and ubuntu 13.10.  I recently upgraded to 14.04 lts and the problem and activator now works out of the box.  The install was fresh.  The only meaningful packages I had installed were kde-workspace-bin and openjdk7.

Comment: It doesn't happen on centos 6.2 either for me.